# window.onblur not working

Tags: javascript, window, onblur

I can't seem to get window.onblur to work properly.

```
window.onblur = console.log('blur');
```

When the listener is applied to the window, it just runs when the page is loaded, but not when the window looses focus.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
window.onblur = function() { console.log('blur'); }
```

Comment: Now... how do I get it to work if the user switches tabs or clicks in the address bar?

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII I think this might do the trick, but you may well have forgotten all about it by now. I had a similar problem and this was my solution for now.

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII Checkout the Page Visibility API on MDN. the `visibiltychange` event might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 25):

Ryudice has told you what to do, but didn't explain *why* it didn't work your way. Understanding the mechanics of it will help you work out how to proceed further.

The reason is that your original code is *running* the `console.log('blur')` command immediately, and using the return value of that call as the window onblur event.

The return value of `console.log()` varies between browsers, but for the sake of argument, lets say it returns a boolean `true` value. This means that your original code is the equivalent of writing this:

```
window.onblur = true;
```

Which clearly isn't going to work as you expect.

What you need is for `window.onblur` to be set to a function that will be called each time the `onblur` event is triggered. This is achieved by wrapping the code in a `function() {}`, as per Ryudice's answer.

You can also achieve it in simple cases by not supplying the brackets on the function name you want to call. But this method only works if you don't have any arguments you want to pass to the function, so wouldn't be suited to your `console.log` example.

Hope that helps. If you're still puzzled, there's lots of resources on the web. Try googling for phrases like "javascript passing functions as arguments", and see what comes up.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onblur = () => console.log( "blur" );
```

Comment: @FlorianEck Yes it will, that's just an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), it's a standard part of JavaScript (added in ES6, 2015).