# JavaScript onURLChange

Tags: javascript, url, onchange

i want when the url of browser change to do something.
if (url.change){
do something
}

I don't want to use php. only javascript and html.
Thank you

Comment: Do you mean [`onhashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onhashchange)? Because if the _URL_ actually changed, your whole page will be "lost" and there's no chance for your JavaScript to be executed. The best bet for that would be [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload).

Comment: For SPA applications this should work https://itsopensource.com/how-to-call-a-function-on-URL-change-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done.

You can't monitor changes to the url from Javascript. There is a [window.onblur-event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361188/window-onblur-not-working), that monitors if one is leaving your page. But you can't determine what the new url in the browser is or will be.

And php works server side, so monitoring a client side change isn't an option.